# why do ncol and nrow return NULL value?

Tags: r

I useBut when I want to print number of rows and columns with nrow() and ncol(), it returns as NULL. how can I fix it?

Comment: It works for me `library(AER); data('Medicaid1986'); nrow(Medicaid1986); ncol(Medicaid1986)`

Comment: Me too, `nrow(Medicaid1986)` gives 996 and `ncol(Medicaid1986)` gives 14. Can you perhaps show a sample of the script that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Dont assign the data in an object. Just do

```
data("Medicaid1986")
nrow(Medicaid1986)
#[1] 996
ncol(Medicaid1986)
#[1] 14
```

If you want to change its name, do it after you load the data, i.e.

```
data("Medicaid1986")
df <- Medicaid1986
```

If you do it your way, it returns a single value which is the string of the name,

```
medicaid1986 <- data("Medicaid1986")
medicaid1986
[1] "Medicaid1986"
```